# Shell: Write for ... in arguments into a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
for i in "a" "a b"; do
    echo $i;
done
```

echoes:

```
a
a b
```

How can I write something like `for i in $input; do` and assign `"a" "a b"` to `input`? The whitespace is important. Otherwise `$(echo ...)` would work.

*Edit*: The question is not about files and neither about some input, which can be caught using `$@`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using bash, you could do this:

```
input=("a" "a b")

for i in "${input[@]}"; do
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: @Zack The question is tagged as `bash`.  Are we now requiring that, in addition to being correct, answers need to be POSIX conformant, even if the OP asks for bash?

Comment: You should have at least noted them as nonstandard.  But it is my considered opinion that one should never use bashisms: if there is no way to accomplish something in portable shell, the correct choice is to use Perl or Python instead.

Comment: @Zack Right. Even if a script is never meant to be used by anybody but the OP, in an environment that *they* control, they're not allowed to use "bashisms", despite the fact that "bashisms" are shorter, faster, and less quirky than POSIX standard shell.  The question is not "What's the best tool for this job?" the question is "How do you accomplish this is bash?"  If the OP wanted a lecture on the virtues of python over the shell he could go read about it on the myriad of sites that discuss that issue.

Comment: "Even if..." YES! A *vital* part of knowing how to write good shell scripts is knowing when *not* to write a shell script.

Comment: @Zack: Then let us all immediately uninstall Bash. And Python 3 and Python 2.6 or later or anything later than Perl 5.8. ...There is a time for portability and there's a time when it doesn't matter or the more powerful, newer features are more powerful and more necessary. Yes, it's true, it's important to know the difference (or when to use something else entirely), but every question about Bash should not trigger a compulsion to hawk portability or "use something else" unless it's pertinent to the question.

Comment: @Zack Would you freeze time (with respect to the capabilities of "shell scripts") at 1992's publication of POSIX.2 forever? There are surely a great many cases where other languages make more sense -- but modern shells (in part on account of features such as arrays) are undoubtedly useful in situations where older ones were not.

Comment: ... especially when the OP specifically asks for a bash script!

Comment: The script is only used to start a script of mine a few times with different parameters. Nothing special and definitely nothing anyone else will ever read. Now I'm a big fan of Python!!! and would never use such strange bash command for production. But for quick and dirty scripts such tricks are really valuable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, pretty much!  I really don't see the point in using a shell script for anything even moderately complicated ... unless what you need is extreme portability.  (You are aware that several thankfully-now-hardly-ever-seen proprietary Unixes *really did* freeze the behavior of their shell and related utilities at roughly the point you mention, yes?)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I wouldn't freeze anything *except* the shell.  As I said to Charles, I see extreme portability as just about the only reason ever to use the shell for something complicated.

Comment: Not sure why there is so much hostility towards portability.  You would think that the troubles encountered trying to change `/bin/sh` from bash on Debian would have sufficiently demonstrated that portability really is important.  It is important to mention it in *any* question tagged `shell` or explicitly `bash` because many people are not even aware that there is an issue.

Comment: @Tim: re: "Even if a script is never meant to be used by anybody but the OP".   The best tools are those that find use where the author never intended.  If people focus on writing tools only meant for themselves, they will never write anything useful.  If people do not practice habits designed to make their tools portable, they will have a more difficult time writing useful tools.  Flexibility and portability are *always* primary considerations when writing software.

Comment: There are only 2 kinds of people that write shell scripts: those that have been burned by portability issues, and those that will be.

Comment: @WilliamPursell You write your code for a target language.  If you're writing a program for bash, one shouldn't expect for it to run on dash.  If you're writing general-purpose install scripts to run on unknown machines, you write using the POSIX standard to maximize compatibility.  You choose your tools to fit your purpose. I don't skip Java generics just because they're not backwards compatible.  I use new features as they come along and document the minimum requirements to run my code.

Comment: In keeping with the spirit of meaningless anecdotes: there are only 2 kinds of programmers: those who leverage new features and those who complain about them :)

Comment: @Tim :)  New features are indeed a good thing, and I'm not complaining about them.  The sad fact is there are a *lot* of people who use features of bash and are not even aware that those features are not valid sh, and they don't even know that bash isn't sh.  sh is different than java or perl simply because there are so many flavors still in use, and it is so fundamental.  I think  "writing a program for bash" is a mistake.  A program is much more useful if it is written for sh, and in cases where bash is not necessary, there's no need to limit the program to bash.

Comment: Note that I'm not at all complaining about your answer, I just don't understand why Zack's comments are being dismissed, since he raises very valid concerns.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done portably with the `"$@"` construct for command-line arguments.

However, if you don't need the *actual* command line arguments anymore, you can use `set` to replace their contents:

```
input='"a" "a b"'
eval set fnord $input
shift
for i in "$@"; do
    echo $i
done
```

You should be aware that *merely having asked this question* suggests that you are approaching the complexity level where you should switch to a less limited scripting language (Perl and Python are the usual choices).

Comment: shell functions get their own command line params, so it doesn't blow away the original args.  `echoi() { for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done; } echoi "a" "a b"`

Comment: That's good if the surrounding context allows you to use a shell function, but sometimes that's not an option; we don't know what the OP's larger situation is.

Comment: Note that this is such a common idiom, it is the default.  You can omit `in "$@` and just write: `for i; do echo $i; done`